# Retrieve Interim Results in SQL Transaction

Tags: javascript, sql, promise, transactions

I have tried writing a SQL-Transaction in JavaScript but stumbled upon two issues that I just can't seem to figure out.

a) This always gives me a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong or how I can properly handly errors with promise. Catching them after every .then() hasn't worked either

b) Is there a way to get interim results in transactions so that I can make my result.insertId work? I still want the rollback to function after every query.

```js
return db.promise().query("START TRANSACTION") // db is a sql pool
    .then(() => {
    return db.promise().query(
        SqlString.format( 
        `INSERT INTO Standort (Street, Number, City, PLZ) 
        VALUES('${street}',${number},'${city}',${plz})`
        )
    )
    })
    .then ((result) => { 
    console.log("first result: " + result.insertId);
    return db.promise().query(
        SqlString.format( 
        `INSERT INTO Table1 (Table1ID) 
        VALUES(${result.insertId})`
        )
    )
    })
    .then((result) => { 
    return db.promise().query(
        SqlString.format(
        `INSERT INTO Table2 (Name, Table2ID) 
        VALUES('${vorname}', ${result.insertId})`
        )
    )
    })
    .then((result) => { 
    return db.promise().query(
        SqlString.format(
        `INSERT INTO Table3 (Email, Table3ID) 
        VALUES( '${email}',${result.insertId})`
        )
    )
    })
    .then((result) => {
        return db.promise().query("COMMIT");
    })
    .catch((error) => { 
        console.log(error); 
        db.promise().query("ROLLBACK"); 
        db.promise().query("RELEASE");
    }
    );
```

Comment: @Bravo so you mean there is no way to get the results in between?

Comment: @Bravo ok if I run return right before every `db.promise().query(..` and move the `db.promise().query("COMMIT");` to its own .then() it still does not give me the result in the queries and throws the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand..Where exactly do I need to put the await? Could you put your suggestion as an answer, please?

Comment: It refers to every preceding query result, so each result passed into `.then`

Comment: Yes the first result already is undefined. And the error is `sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'undefined' in 'field list'"`

Comment: the error is from the second insert - since the first succeeded ... odd that you say `result` is undefined, yet the error suggests that the query had an error in the field list, not the values list - which would suggest that the query string didn't *fail* on `result.insertId` - which it would, if `result` is `undefined`

Comment: So, the console.log you've shown in the code outputs `first result: undefined` - and that's an accurate representation of the code you actually use?

Comment: Please try to post formatted code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with `result.insertId` is that `result` is an array

you want `result[0].insertId`

The reason you are getting an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is because you're throwing an error in `.catch(` which is not being handled

This is most likely because you are executing the two queries essentially "in parallel" - you need to chain those queries as follows:

The reason you would've been getting `result` as `undefined` is because you were not returning anything in the .then's (original code in question - now edited)

lastly, as per comments, `result.insertID` would be `undefined` since the insert id is returned in `result.insertId` - case is important

```
return db.promise().query("START TRANSACTION") // db is a sql pool
.then(() => {
    return db.promise().query(
        SqlString.format(
            `INSERT INTO Standort (Street, Number, City, PLZ) 
        VALUES('${street}',${number},'${city}',${plz})`));
})
.then((result) => {
    console.log("first result: " + result);
    return db.promise().query(
        SqlString.format(
            `INSERT INTO Table1 (Table1ID) 
        VALUES(${result[0].insertId})`));
})
.then((result) => {
    return db.promise().query(
        SqlString.format(
            `INSERT INTO Table2 (Name, Table2ID) 
        VALUES('${vorname}', ${result[0].insertId})`));
})
// note this alternative syntax ... ([result])
.then(([result]) => {
    return db.promise().query(
        SqlString.format(
            `INSERT INTO Table3 (Email, Table3ID) 
        VALUES( '${email}',${result.insertId})`));
})
.then((result) => {
    return db.promise().query("COMMIT");
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    return db.promise().query("ROLLBACK").then(() => db.promise().query("RELEASE"))
})
.catch((error) => {
    // error in rollback or release!
    console.log(error);
})
```

The added `.catch` is there in case the `ROLLBACK` or `RELEASE` rejects

Alternatively, using async/await with try/catch:
(edited out the SQL queries as they are unchanged)

```
async function someFunction() {
    // ...
    // ...
    try {
        await db.promise().query("START TRANSACTION"); // db is a sql pool
        let result = await db.promise().query(.....);
        console.log("first result: " + result);
        result = await db.promise().query(.....);
        result = await db.promise().query(.....);
        // note the syntax change here too
        // either syntax can be used
        // just means you either use result[0].insertId
        // or result.insertId
        [result] = await db.promise().query(.....);
        return db.promise().query("COMMIT");
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Error inserting records");
        console.log(error);
        try {
            await db.promise().query("ROLLBACK");
            return db.promise().query("RELEASE");
        } catch {
            console.log("Error in ROLLBACK/RELEASE");
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

seeing as your code does a `return` in the first line, I can safely assume you're in a `function` - just make it an `async function`

Comment: I still get the same errors after doing your (first) solution. I think the main problem besides the UnhandledPromiseRejection is that I can't access the results . This goes especially the first one, because there has been an INSERT into the table, so clearly there has to be a result..

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `result.insertID` is undefined

Comment: I'm using the package mysql2 and created a pool on my local instance using the package.

Comment: `first result: [{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":1,"insertId":25,"info":"","serverStatus":3,"warningStatus":0},null]`

Comment: Ok, I don't know why the result obejct looks different this time. But the problem was that I tried to access it with result.insertId instead of doing result[0].insertId

Comment: @codingbudgie updated the answer with all issues covered I believe